# AND/OR operator not filtering as desired

Tags: sql, sql-server, operators

I'm trying pull a list of trucks that are marked as 'Inventory' (status = 'I') that do not have a 'FiWipStatusCode' of 'P', 'B', or 'F'.

Put differently, I want to pull a list of trucks marked as Inventory that DO have a 'fiwipstatuscode' of 'null' or 'C'.

The code below isn't filtering the way I want it to.
thanks!

```
SELECT     InventoryVehicle.StockNo, InventoryVehicle.Status, VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode
FROM       InventoryVehicle
INNER JOIN VehicleSales ON InventoryVehicle.StockNo = VehicleSales.StockNo
WHERE      (InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I') AND (VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'F') AND (InventoryVehicle.Balance > '15000') OR
           (InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I') AND (VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'P') AND (InventoryVehicle.Balance > 15000) OR
           (InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I') AND (VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'B') AND (InventoryVehicle.Balance > 15000) OR
           (InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I') AND (VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode IS NULL) AND (InventoryVehicle.Balance > 15000) OR
           (InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I') AND (VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode = 'C') AND (InventoryVehicle.Balance > 15000)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up precedene of AND and OR.  I think you probably want this:

```
SELECT InventoryVehicle.StockNo, InventoryVehicle.Status, VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode
FROM InventoryVehicle INNER JOIN VehicleSales ON InventoryVehicle.StockNo = VehicleSales.StockNo
WHERE ((InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I') AND (VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'F') AND (InventoryVehicle.Balance > '15000')) OR
                  ((InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I') AND (VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'P') AND (InventoryVehicle.Balance > 15000)) OR
                  ((InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I') AND (VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'B') AND (InventoryVehicle.Balance > 15000)) OR
                  ((InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I') AND (VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode is NULL) AND (InventoryVehicle.Balance > 15000)) OR
                  ((InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I') AND (VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode = 'C') AND (InventoryVehicle.Balance > 15000));
```

Note the () encapsulating each set of AND checks.

And since each group of AND's is now encapsulated you can make it even easier:

```
SELECT InventoryVehicle.StockNo, InventoryVehicle.Status, VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode
FROM InventoryVehicle INNER JOIN VehicleSales ON InventoryVehicle.StockNo = VehicleSales.StockNo
WHERE (InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I' AND VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'F' AND InventoryVehicle.Balance > '15000') OR
      (InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I' AND VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'P' AND InventoryVehicle.Balance > 15000) OR
      (InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I' AND VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'B' AND InventoryVehicle.Balance > 15000) OR
      (InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I' AND VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode is NULL AND InventoryVehicle.Balance > 15000) OR
      (InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I' AND VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode = 'C' AND InventoryVehicle.Balance > 15000);
```

And, since two of the filter parameters are the same in each case you can simplify it even further:

```
SELECT InventoryVehicle.StockNo, InventoryVehicle.Status, VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode
FROM InventoryVehicle INNER JOIN VehicleSales ON InventoryVehicle.StockNo = VehicleSales.StockNo
WHERE InventoryVehicle.Status = 'I'
AND InventoryVehicle.Balance > '15000'
AND (
    VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'F' OR
    VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'P' OR
    VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'B' OR
    VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode is NULL OR
    VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode = 'C'
);
```

Comment: I had to add a left outer join but then it worked perfectly! thanks very much!

Comment: I would even go a step further and get rid of almost all of those parenthesis. They are doing nothing but adding noise which makes it even hard to see what is going on. +1

Comment: I'm probably missing something looking at that final version, but for what value of `FiWipStatusCode` would just *this part* **not** be true: `VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'F' OR VehicleSales.FiWipStatusCode <> 'P'`

Comment: @Richardissimo Yeah, I deleted that comment after I reread yours. Good point, but it's still the same logic, albeit flawed.

Comment: ... So that whole section containing `FiWipStatusCode` will always be true. Agree, it's in the original, just more obvious in this form.

Comment: Something not equal to `F` **OR** something not equal to `P`. So if we have `P` it will be selected (not equal to `F`) and if we have `F` it is also selected (not equal to `P`). What gives?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people get these two operators mixed up. 
In real life we say, “bring me all the pants **AND** shirts” and we expect to receive all of both items.

SQL sees the request differently and will return only the pants-with-shirts as well as the shirts-with-pants, but will not return pants only or shirts only.

In SQL you need say “bring me all the pants **OR** shirts” if you want all of both items.

Here are couple of "good rules of thumb" to follow.

1) The **AND** operator displays a record **ONLY** if **ALL** the conditions on both sides of the **AND** statement are true.

2) The **OR** operator displays a record if **ANY** of the conditions on both sides of the **AND** statement are true.

This is where JOIN statements come in handy.

Hope this helps.